# Wireless connection problems

Tags: wireless, connection

Upgrade manager rec. Ubuntu12.4 which I downloaded using a wireless connection.  Worked fine for 5 days then lost connectivity, can only connect using wired.  Am being asked to 'authenticate ' with wireless password and admin. password but nothing works.  The signal is there and so is the network but no recognition.  Have also tried changing password.

Someone suggested re-installing but I would have to do that from Ubuntu Software Manager and use usb or CD.

I am a novice at this as you'll have gathered.

any help please.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

- There may be a problem of the network (e.g. the wifi router). Have you tried on a different wireless network? Do other users connect normally to this wireless network?
- Let's make sure that your wireless card did not break. Download Ubuntu on a USB stick and boot Ubuntu without installing (on memory). Does the wireless work there?
- If you don't mind loosing all network settings and passwords that Ubuntu Network Manager remembers from previous connections, you could try to reset your network Manager:

  1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and
  2. type `sudo apt-get --purge remove network-manager` on the terminal.
  3. You will be asked to confirm that you want to do it.
  4. When finished, then type `sudo apt-get install network-manager`
- It may be that a new kernel version was downloaded during some system update; and this kernel version does not properly support your wireless adapter hardware. If this is the case, when you turn on your computer, there should be a black screen with a list of Ubuntu kernel versions to choose. If this is the case, try by starting your computer with an older version, than the one selected by default.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and type `lspci | grep Network`. This should list your network controllers, and it should be obvious by the name that one of them is the wireless. Please post the model here, or search around to see whether other users of this device have the same problem with the same version of Ubuntu